# C output question

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C output question…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551821/c-output-question)

Why its o/p is %%??

```
int main(void)
{
  printf("%%%\n");
  return 0;
}
```

while for below program o/p is %?

```
int main(void)
{
  printf("%%%");
  return 0;
}
```

can tou tell me where is the difference actually??

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Have you thought about trying it yourself?

Comment: Have you thought about reading the documentation of the function you are using?

Comment: Since this has an undefined behavior I won't say -1.

Answer (score 4):

It's undefined behaviour. Section 7.19.6.1/9 of C99 states:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

and none of the preceding sections allow a conversion specifier of a space. They are limited to characters from the set `diouxXfFeEgGaAcsPn%`.

Comment: Space is a valid modifier for conversion specifiers, but `%` is not a valid next character in the specifier.

Comment: @R: yes, the space is a valid modifier for signed conversions but, as you say, `%` is not a signed conversion. I think one of the paragraphs in the standard says that the `%%` must be of _exactly_ that form as well (no modifiers allowed).