# C output question

Tags: c, linux, printf

Why its output is %%??

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        printf("% % %\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you really have to ask it on 2 sites within 25 minutes?

Answer (score 4):

It's undefined behaviour and absolutely *anything* can happen. Section 7.19.6.1/9 of C99 states:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

and none of the preceding sections allow a conversion specifier of a space. They are limited to characters from the set `diouxXfFeEgGaAcsPn%`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use one `%`, it sees it as string (because it lacks other specifiers) and output `%`. If you use `%%`, it is to print `%` in output. if you use `%%%` the first two will be considered as outputting `%` and the last one as single "character". so you only get two `%`.

Comment: I am no C expert, but wouldn't the spaces matter? It might just be undefined behavior; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551810/c-output-question